Python MCTS Function is always choosing the last available move instead of the best one
I've been writing a MCTS implementation in Python 3. It doesn't have any code errors, however, the searcher always picks the last move available rather than the optimal one.
I've tried to figure out why to no avail, and so I turn to people who know more about MCTS than I do. I suspect it's something to do with the way the code chooses the best node to expand. Apologies if my code is messy, this is my first bigger project.
import math
import random
import copy

class Node:  # handles the nodes for the tree
    def __init__(self, game, parent=None):
        self.game = game
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = []
        self.numVisited = 0  # number of times node has been traversed
        self.numWins = 0  # number of accumulated wins
        self.untriedActions = game.getActions()  # list of things to still be searched

    def isExpanded(self):
        return len(self.untriedActions) == 0  # no more actions to try means that it's expanded

    def isTerminal(self):
        return self.game.winner() is not None  # if there is a winner the game is over

    def expand(self):
        assert not self.isExpanded()
        chosenAction = self.untriedActions.pop()  # pick an unused action
        newGame = copy.deepcopy(self.game)  # Use deep copy to ensure new instance
        newGame.applyAction(chosenAction)
        newNode = Node(newGame, parent=self)
        self.children.append(newNode)  # push the new node into the children of this one
        return newNode

    def backpropagate(self, result):  # send things up the tree
        self.numVisited += 1
        # If the current node's player is the same as the result, it's a win for this node
        if result == self.game.player:
            self.numWins += 1  # results are formatted 0 for a loss and 1 for a win
        else:
            self.numWins -= 1

        if self.parent is not None:  # if this is not the root node, then we make sure to go further up
            self.parent.backpropagate(-result)  # Negate the result for the opponent

    def scoreUCT(self):  # calculate the UCB formula for a given node
        c = math.sqrt(2)
        assert self.parent is not None  # we should never ask for the score of the root node
        return (self.numWins / self.numVisited) + c * math.sqrt(math.log(self.parent.numVisited) / self.numVisited)

    def rolloutResult(self):  # plays a random game from the node's state and returns result
        return self.game.randomGame()

    def selectBestChild(self):  # picks the most promising child node by UCB scores
        bestScore = -float('inf')  # Initialize to negative infinity to ensure any score is higher
        bestChild = None

        for child in self.children:  # loop through the children and pick the best one
            score = child.scoreUCT()
            if score > bestScore:
                bestScore = score
                bestChild = child
        return bestChild

    def prettyPrint(self):
        print('=====')
        print(f'State: {self.game.state}')
        print(f'Player: {self.game.player}')
        print(f'Number of visits: {self.numVisited}')
        print(f'Number of wins: {self.numWins}')
        print(f'Children: {len(self.children)}')

        if len(self.children) > 0:
            for child in self.children:
                child.prettyPrint()


class Search:
    def __init__(self, game):
        self.game = game
        self.root = Node(game)

    def iteration(self):
        selectedNode = self.root
        while not selectedNode.isTerminal():
            if not selectedNode.isExpanded():
                selectedNode = selectedNode.expand()
            else:
                selectedNode = selectedNode.selectBestChild()

        result = selectedNode.rolloutResult()
        selectedNode.backpropagate(result)

    def treeSearch(self, numIts):
        for i in range(numIts):
            self.iteration()

        bestScore = -float('inf')
        bestChild = None
        for child in self.root.children:  # loop through the children and pick the best one
            score = child.numVisited
            if score > bestScore:
                bestScore = score
                bestChild = child
        return bestChild

    def treePrint(self):
        self.root.prettyPrint()


class Game:  # game logic
    def __init__(self, state, player=1):
        self.state = state[:]
        self.player = player

    def getActions(self):  # return a list of all actions possible from current game state
        if self.winner() is not None:
            return []

        possibleActions = []
        for i in range(len(self.state)):
            if self.state[i] == 0:
                possibleActions.append(i)
        return possibleActions

    def applyAction(self, action):  # apply a given action to the game to change the state.
        assert self.state[action] == 0
        self.state[action] = self.player
        # V THIS IS IMPORTANT
        self.player *= -1

    def randomGame(self):  # play a random game from the current position
        copyGame = copy.deepcopy(self)  # Use deep copy to ensure new instance
        while copyGame.winner() is None:  # play until the game finishes
            possMoves = copyGame.getActions()
            copyGame.applyAction(random.choice(possMoves))
        return copyGame.winner()

    def winner(self):
        for i in range(0, len(self.state) - 2):
            if self.state[i] != 0 and self.state[i] == self.state[i + 1] == self.state[i + 2]:
                return self.state[i]
        if 0 not in self.state:
            return 1

        return None


# Example game and search
# This game needs a 3-in-a-row to win, and so playing after the two -1s would be a win for -1. 
# However, this will play the final "square" in the array
# If you add more rows to the array, it will still choose the last one.
g = Game([0, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, 0, 0], -1)
s = Search(g)
best_child = s.treeSearch(100)
print(best_child.game.state)


What's your expected output? Your code looks pretty decent. Post it here to also get a review.

@user24714692 The page I read about MCTS suggested that that was how to do it. Even if I change that the issue persists.

Your question boils down to wi/ni + c*sqrt(ln(N)/ni). Right? If so, I see no problem.

@user24714692 yes but that is the correct UCB  formula. I just don't understand why it's not playing correctly

Make your inputs small. Then, print out the value of equation for a series of samples and start inspecting. I see the equation is correct. There must be something else, somewhere else. Don't really know.
